# Font size (in pt) of references using amsplain

Tags: fonts, bibliographies, fontsize, amsart

I have the following document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
Hello world!
\bibliographystyle{amsplain}
\begin{thebibliography}{13}
\bibitem[1]{1}
 A. Einstein. ``The theory of everything''.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

**I wanted to make sure that the text in the references is in 10 pt font.** I read somewhere that amsplain by default uses \footnotesize, which translates to 10 pt when using amsart 12 pt. However, I was worried whether my particular set up may not actually result in the default 10 pt font that amsplain uses.

Comment: You can 'inject' a `\fontsize` command into `\thebibliography`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - `\footnotesize` or `\fontsize`? :-)

Comment: @Mico: `\footnotesize` could be a solution, but you can not be sure that is actually `10pt`, so `\fontsize{10}{15}\selectfont`, but the baselinestretch is to be adapted, for sure.

Answer (score 8):

The size of print in the references section, when using `amsart`, is defined within
the `thebibliography` environment, not by `amsplain`.  It is, furthermore, defined in
a user-modifiable manner, via the command `\bibliofont`, which (in `amsart`) does
default to `\footnotesize`.

Further investigation shows that `\footnotesize` is equated to `\Small`, which
(in `amsart`) follows the size progression common to all AMS document classes:

- `\normalsize` -- defaults to `10pt` unless overridden by a `\documentclass` option
  (you have specified `12pt`)
- `\small` -- one size down; for `12pt` this is `11pt` (actually 10.95pt in the
  computer modern scheme of things)
- `\Small` -- two sizes down, and the default for `\footnotesize`; for `12pt`
  this is `10pt`, which is what you are looking for, unless `\footnotesize` has
  been reassigned
- `\SMALL` -- three sizes down; `9pt` for the `12pt` option

So, unless you have reassigned any of the "alternate" names to use different size values,
your references will be set in `10pt` type.

Answer (score 2):

I used the `etoolbox` and appended to `\thebibliography` the command the `\fontsize{10}{15}\selectfont` command.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}%
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\apptocmd{\thebibliography}{\fontsize{10}{15}\selectfont}{}{}%
\begin{document}
Hello world!
\bibliographystyle{amsplain}
\begin{thebibliography}{13}
\bibitem[1]{1}
 A. Einstein. ``The theory of everything''.
\bibitem[2]{1}
 S. Cooper. ``Penny, Penny, Penny''.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know the current font at any given moment, you can use the following trick:

```
\newcommand{\whatsthefont}{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
  \noexpand\texttt{\expandafter\string\the\font=\fontname\font}}\x
}
```

The `\edef` ensures that `\expandafter\string\the\font` and `\fontname\font` are expanded when the font hasn't yet been changed to the typewriter font that's then used for typesetting the strings. Note that `\the\font` means the internal font identifier for the current font and that `\fontname\font` expands to the name of the TFM file corresponding to the current font.

Complete example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\whatsthefont}{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
  \noexpand\texttt{\expandafter\string\the\font=\fontname\font}}\x
}

\begin{document}
Hello world!

\whatsthefont

\begin{thebibliography}{13}
\bibitem[1]{1}  \whatsthefont
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thus you see that in the bibliography a ten point font is selected.

The same after adding `\usepackage{newtxtext}:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The good news up front: If you use the `amsart` document class with class option `12pt`, the material in the bibliography section will indeed be set at `10pt`.

Establishing this result takes a bit of sleuthing. If we delve into the file `amsart.cls` (which defines the amsart document class), one finds the following definition of the `bibliography` environment:

```
\newenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{%
  % ... (details irrelevant)
  \normalfont\bibliofont % ... (details irrelevant)
  % ... (details irrelevant)
```

where `\bibliofont` was defined a few lines earlier as

```
\newcommand{\bibliofont}{\footnotesize}
```

Still earlier in the same file, `\footnotesize` is set via the instruction `\def\footnotesize{\Small}`, and `\Small` in turn is defined via

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Small}{\@xsetfontsize\Small 4%
   %% ... further details irrelevant
}
```

The `\@xsetfontsize` macro, which takes two arguments, is defined rather densely as

```
\def\@xsetfontsize#1#2{%
  \chardef\@currsizeindex#2\relax
  \edef\@tempa{\@nx\@setfontsize\@nx#1%
    \@xp\ifcase\@xp\@currsizeindex\@typesizes
      \else{99}{99}\fi}%
  \@tempa
}
```

As I said, this is a bit dense. The most relevant macro in this chunk of code is `\@typesizes`, which for the `12pt` document class option is defined as follows:

```
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\def\@mainsize{12}\def\@ptsize{2}%
  \def\@typesizes{%
    \or{7}{8}\or{8}{10}\or{9}{11}\or{10}{12}\or{\@xipt}{13}%
    \or{\@xiipt}{14}% normalsize
    \or{\@xivpt}{17}\or{\@xviipt}{20}\or{\@xxpt}{24}%
    \or{\@xxvpt}{30}\or{\@xxvpt}{30}}%
  \normalsize \linespacing=\baselineskip
}
```

The bunch of `\or` statements is the key to solving the puzzle: Since the second argument of `\Small` is "4", the *fourth* condition is true, i.e., `{10}{12}` is the fontsize and the baselineskip.

Phew!

Incidentally, the `amsart` document class automatically loads the `amsmath` and `amsfonts` packages -- no need to load them via `\usepackage` statements.